# How to map X Y from the screen plane to a transformed plane that has been zoomed, rotated, translated and put in perspective

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, 3d

I'm making a [CSS 3D viewer on Codepen](http://codepen.io/eternalsunshineofspotlessmind/pen/bGRdPoz) and I'm currently trying to move the models on the surface using my mouse.

The problem is that the "mousemove" event always give me the mouse X Y relative to the webpage (from top left corner to bottom right), but my scene is a square that has been zoomed, rotated, translated and put in perspective. I know all values of zoom, rotation, translation and perspective (as distance from origin).

How do I map my mouse X Y as X Y on the scene?

This is my scene where I intend to project my mouse X and Y:
[image]

This is the plane in which my mouse X Y are calculated (Y as distance from top and X as distance from left):
[image]

EDIT:
The center of the webpage and the center of the scene is coincident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you want to find a point $(x',y')$ such that after applying a mapping given by your computer to that point, you get a point $(x,y)$ for some given $x$ and $y$.

If so, simply "undo" the mapping.

**Zoom/Dilation**: If the zoom is $200\%$ (for example) with respect to the origin, you'd need to scale down by $2$, i.e. convert $(x,y)$ to $(x/2,y/2).$

**Rotation**: It suffices to be able to rotate a point an angle $\theta$ about the origin. If $(x',y')$ is a rotation $\theta$ about the origin of $(x,y)$, then
$$\begin{pmatrix}x' \\ y'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}$$

**Translation**: This is easy. If you have translated up $a$ units and right $b$ units, simply translate up $-a$ units and right $-b$ units.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "perspective".

Comment: Sorry to say that this wasn't even the problem I intended to solve really. Perspective shouldn't mess things up as it's just the distance from the origin, at least I think it shouldn't count. By the way thank you for your answer, I've solved the problem by marking the vertices of the floor and triangulated X Y of the mouse. You can try the fiddle, now the link works.
I think your answer is somewhat correct, but in reverse, as I always have the coordinate of the screen plane, therefore I have to transform my mouse X Y in order to project on the floor of the 3D scene. Am I right?

Comment: @FredoCorleone Yes, I think that's correct